# Why is my PySpark dataframe join operation writing an empty result?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two PySpark dataframes that I'm trying to join into a new dataframe. The join operation seems to show a null dataframe.

I'm using Jupyter notebooks to evaluate the code, on a PySpark kernel, on a cluster with a single master, 4 workers, YARN for resource allocation.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id,udf
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import DenseVector
firstelement=udf(lambda v:float(v[1]),FloatType())

a = [{'c_id': 'a', 'cv_id': 'b', 'id': 1}, {'c_id': 'c', 'cv_id': 'd', 'id': 2}]
ip = spark.createDataFrame(a)
b = [{'probability': DenseVector([0.99,0.01]), 'id': 1}, {'probability': DenseVector([0.6,0.4]), 'id': 2}]
op = spark.createDataFrame(b)

op.show() #shows the df
#probability, id
#[0.99, 0.01], 1
##probability is a dense vector, id is bigint

ip.show() #shows the df
#c_id, cv_id, id
#a,b,1
##c_id and cv_id are strings, id is bigint

op_final = op.join(ip, ip.id == op.id).select('c_id','cv_id',firstelement('probability')).withColumnRenamed('<lambda>(probability)','probability')

op_final.show() #gives a null df

#but the below seems to work, however, quite slow
ip.collect() 
op.collect()
op_final.collect()
op_final.show() #shows the joined df
```

Perhaps it's my lack of expertise with Spark, but could someone please explain why I'm able to see the first two dataframes, but not the joined dataframe unless I use collect()?

Comment: its a udf, its defined in row 3:  firstelement=udf(lambda v:float(v[1]),FloatType())

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. You can also do `firstelement('probability').alias("probability")` and avoid the `withColumnRenamed` call after.

Comment: ok, cool, I'll try that to optimize my code. any thoughts on the issue, though?

Comment: Sorry, I can't recreate your issue.Your code works fine for me. I tried both `pyspark.ml.linalg.DenseVector` and `pyspark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector`. Can you add in some code to recreate your example DataFrames?

Comment: @pault I have thought if it has something to do with YARN's memory allocation, since I have observed this sometimes work intermittently. But I haven't been able to replicate the exact circumstances under which it works and it doesn't.

Comment: @pault I have added code to recreate the dfs.

Comment: your code still works fine for me.